# Как удалить старые ядра в  Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Как удалить старые ядра в  Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тоже самое можно выполнить при помощи aptitude

1. Посмотреть список установленных ядер:

   ```
   sudo aptitude search linux-image
   ```
2. Отобрать ненужные (...) и удалить:

   ```
   sudo aptitude remove linux-image-...-generic
   ```

aptitude автоматически предложит удалить и соответствующие удаляемому ядру заголовочные файлы (linux-headers-...) и перенастроит grub

Comment: в последнее время заметил, что aptitude не удаляет-таки заголовочные файлы, поэтому нужно дополнительно удалить и их:
> sudo aptitude remove linux-headers-...

Answer (score 6):

Посмотреть список установленных ядер.

```
dpkg -l | grep "linux-image"
```

Отобрать ненужные (...) и удалить.

```
apt-get remove linux-headers-... linux-headers-...-generic linux-image-...-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

Плюс вариант: через Ubuntu tweak.

Answer (score 0):

А "Система/Администрирование/Очистка системы..." не? Или хочется как-то по необычному? :)